# Make my test_user pass is_authenticated

Tags: python, django, testing

So, the code itself works, but the test fails.  I guess maybe there's some difference between self.user and request.user?  I'm lost.

views.py:

```
def index(request, model_name='item'):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
         return render(request, 'assets/index.html', {})
    else:
         #THIS IS RUNNING
         return redirect(reverse('login'))
```

tests.py:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.client = Client()
    self.user = create_test_user()
    self.user.set_password('test_user')
    self.user.save()
    self.client.login(
        username=self.user.username,
        password=self.user.password)
    print 'AUTHENTICATED? ', self.user.is_authenticated() #PRINTS TRUE

def test_index(self):  # homepage
    response = self.client.get(reverse('index'))
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user.password` is not the plain-text password that you can use to login the user. It is the result of encrypting the password.

You have to save the actual plain-text password (`'test_user'` in this case) and use that to login the user:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.client = Client()
    self.user = create_test_user()
    self.password = 'test_user'
    self.user.set_password(self.password)
    self.user.save()
    self.client.login(
        username=self.user.username,
        password=self.password)
    print 'AUTHENTICATED? ', self.user.is_authenticated() #PRINTS TRUE
```